# Agregar acciones en odoo16

Tags: odoo, odoo16

como puedo modificar las opciones que salen en el boton action para editar un parametro de los objetos seleccionados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que ha intentado?

Comment: Tienes dos maneras de hacerlo. Una es por medio de la interfaz de odoo (web) y otra es creando un modulo. El menú "action" se corresponde con las "action_server".